# node debugger issue: debugger not working when exporting

Tags: node.js, debugging, javascript-debugger

this is one program written for nodeschool/stream-adventure/duplexer-redux. of course this is not gonna fulfill the requirement. But what I want to do is simply put a debugger there and watch what happens--just like set import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace in python. so what is the right way of doing this?

```
   1 var duplexer = require('duplexer');
   2 var through = require('through');
   3 
   4 module.exports = function (counter) {
   5     debugger;
   6     var dic = {};
   7     var tr = through(function (buf) {
   8                 if (dic[buf.country]) {
   9                     dic[buf.country] = 1;
  10                 } else {
  11                     dic[buf.country] = dic[buf.country] + 1;
  12                 }
  13             });
  14     counter.pipe(tr);
  15 
  16     return tr;
  17 }
```

18

Comment: https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector

Comment: Have you gotten a debugger attached? What's actually going wrong?

Comment: should not the program execution stops when it hits debugger? @Aaron Dufour

Comment: Do you start Node with `debug` argument?

Comment: thanks--now I understand. but is there anyway i can stop the execution of node half way? I am using an external testing script file and it is a bit troublesome to manually type "node debug" as some input is provided by the script

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1.Start Node with `debug` argument:

```
$ node debug yourscrupt.js
```

2.Run [the debugger commands](http://nodejs.org/api/debugger.html) as you need.

If you want to debug in the browser, [node-inspector](https://github.com/node-inspector/node-inspector) is a good choice.